# Input a two variable stored in a file to command line of a program

Tags: shell

I have to give different latitude and longitude as input for the program.

Example I have latitude and longitude

```
4.73076  82.1951  
4.84615  84.1463  
4.96153  86.3414  
4.96153  88.6585   
4.84615  90.7317 
4.84615  92.6829
```

I have to give input Above latitude longitude, one by one for below command

access_litho latitude longitude

```
for j in 4.73076  82.1951  4.84615  84.1463  4.96153  86.3414     4.96153  88.6585  4.84615  90.7317 4.84615  92.6829
do
    access_litho $j 
done
```

Comment: If those are stored in a file, `while read -r a b; access_litho "$a" "$b"; done < file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a single flat array:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# make our argument list consist of our elements; $1=lat1, $2=long1; $3=lat2; $4=long2...
set -- 4.73076  82.1951  4.84615  84.1463  4.96153  86.3414     4.96153  88.6585  4.84615  90.7317 4.84615  92.6829

# as long as we have at least two arguments not yet consumed...
while (( $# >= 2 )); do
  access_litho "$1" "$2"  # pass the first two arguments to access_litho
  shift 2                 # then pop them off the front of the list
done
```

---

By contrast, if you have a file with two rows to a line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

exec {orig_stdin}<&0  # copy original stdin FD; note that this requires bash 4.1 or newer
while IFS= read -r lat long; do              # as long as we can read two things from stdin
  access_litho "$lat" "$long" <&$orig_stdin  # pass them to access_litho
done <input-file.txt                         # with stdin redirected from our input file
```